# Firebase - saving data to the database

Tags: jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to learn the new firebase and am following along with the guides on their website but I'm just not getting this part right. How do I save data to the database? Currently my database is empty and what I want to have happen is a user types stuff into a text input and then hits save and that should save whatever the user typed to the db along with his UId and the dateCreated of the data. Here's what I got:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
    // Initialize Firebase. Note that I'm not using the real init details in this post but I assure you they are present in my app
    var config = {
      apiKey: "myApiKey",
      authDomain: "myProject.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://myProject.firebaseio.com",
      storageBucket: "myProject.appspot.com",
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    var database = firebase.database()

    // A whole bunch of other unrelated functions and stuff here

    $('#addMeal').click(function() {
      $('#addBox').slideUp();
      var meal = $('#txtAdd');    var uid = $('#uid').val();
      // If I try to console.log these two vars up here it does actually fire so I don't think there's something wrong with the jquery.

      if(meal.val()) {

        function createMeal(uid, email) {
          firebase.database().ref('meals/').set({
            title: name,
            user: uid,
            dateCreated: new Date()
          });
        }

      } else {
        $('#addBox').addClass('margin_top_xs alert alert-danger').slideDown();
        $('#addMsg').html('<h5 class="centered bold margin_bot_no"> You can\'t enter a blank meal!</h5>');
      }
    });

</script>
```

Also keep in mind that I don't really know which write method I should be using, what I want to do is save every meal to the db without saving over any other data so I don't mind if you answer with a different method for saving data.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to keep a list of meals. So instead of calling `set`, which (as it name implies) sets the data at the location in the database, you should call `push()` which [appends the data to a list of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/save-data#append_to_a_list_of_data):

```
   function createMeal(uid, email) {
      firebase.database().ref('meals/').push({
        title: name,
        user: uid,
        dateCreated: new Date()
      });
    }
```

The documentation I linked explains this in more detail, so I recommend (re)reading it.

Comment: Thank you but it did not work. My db is still empty :(

Comment: Saving additional data to a list-like location requires the use of `push()`. That could be caused by many problems, none of which I can easily see from the code you posted. If you post a **minimal** jsfiddle/jsbin that reproduces the problem, I'll have a look.